# dynamic array declaration in different ways

Tags: c++, arrays, heap-memory

I know that `int* array = new int [n];` allocates memory space in heap.

But if I declare something like that: `int array[n];` in codeblocks it compile successfully, but if I move it to visual studio, it comes out of error.

What I want to ask is:

1. What does `int[n]` really do and how does it compare to heap allocation? What is the difference between them?
2. What the error may come out if I use `int array[n]` instead of `int* array = new int [n];`?

Comment: A variable length shouldn't be used for statically-sized arrays. Codeblocks accepts it because GCC probably has support for it as an extenstion.

Comment: Taken from GCC docs: `Variable-length automatic arrays are allowed in ISO C99, and as an extension GCC accepts them in C90 mode and in C++.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int array[n]` declares an array on the stack, not the heap. In standard C++ `n` must be a compile time constant, however some compilers have an extension that allows for variable length arrays declared in this form without a compile time constant `n`. It's not standard and probably shouldn't be used.

`int array[n]` can cause a couple problems over `int* array = new int [n];`:

- If `n` is big enough you can cause a stack overflow. Or if the array is a class member and you create a large array of the class.
- If `array` is a class member *moving* could be as expensive as *copying*
- If `array` is a class member and you have given out pointers to the array and `move` the class, the pointers now refer to a post-moved object, or if random memory if the object was also destroyed. Either way, bad.

Comment: So is there any potential problem come out when I use `int array[n]`?

Comment: Then why some compilers do the extensions for it? Thx

Comment: @Liang-YuPan [Problems with Arrays](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-cwhy-variable-length-arrays/184401444)

Comment: @Liang-YuPan Because it's in the C99 standard (C++ shares a lot in the C standard), and it's convenient. But it's not in the C++ standard

Comment: @Liang-YuPan Perhaps you should accept the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 3):

GCC has an extension in C++ that allows `int array[n]` where `n` is not a compile time constant value. The standard language doesn't allow you to use non-constant value for `n` in such a case (it is allowed in C99).

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your questions correctly, then I can answer both.

1. `int array[10]` is allocated on the stack, whereas `int *array = new int[10]` is allocated on the heap. Usually, stack arrays only work with a constant number of elements, so `int array[n]` is not allowed in C90 (as long as `n` is not constant).
2. MinGW (which is the version of the GCC compiler that codeblocks uses on windows) has an extension which does allow you to write `int array[n]` in C90 mode, where `n` is not constant. Visual C++ does not allow this.

Answer (score 2):

when you write `int array[n]`, that means you are performing a static allocation. i.e. memory will be allocated at the compile time. So using a variable length here will result in a compile time error.